# How can I foreach over this piece of json

Tags: php, json

Im trying to iterate over the file https://alexa.rob-balmbra.co.uk/tracker/mapping.json

Im trying to loop over each name as in "4-72", however i want access to its contents and its name.

Im doing a search in its content and when I have matched the code, I need to subsequently get the key as in '4-72', etc...

Every time I use foreach i get the contents of the json file rather than the key and the contents.

Comment: Would be useful to see what you have so far, but have you seen `foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)`

Comment: I would use json_decode and then foreach over the resulting array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: How you are getting the value of `mapping.json` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Fetch the JSON file and decode it into an associative array
$json = json_decode( file_get_contents('https://alexa.rob-balmbra.co.uk/tracker/mapping.json'), true );

//This is the code you want to search for
$searchCode = "03013";

//Loop through the json array, get key and data
foreach($json as $key=>$data){
    //If the code matches what you're searching for, echo the key out and move past the foreach loop.
    if($data["code"] == $searchCode){
        echo "The service name is: " . $key;
        break;
    }
}

//You don't need this here. I just used it so I could see all the codes.
echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, 1) . '</pre>';
```

The code explained:

1. Go and get the JSON file from the web page
2. Decode the JSON file into an associative array so PHP can work on it
3. Set up a search code
4. For all the keys, search each code to see if it matches the search code
5. If there is a match, Show the respective key.

Answer (score 0):

> Every time I use foreach i get the contents of the json file rather than the key and the contents.

Have you turned the JSON string into an array?

```
$jsonValues = json_decode($jsonString,true) ;

foreach($jsonValues as $key=>$data) {
  // do your thing here
}
```